# Invariance of curves represented by vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

In Tom apostol Vol. 1 Sec 14.5 example 3-
**Invariance under a change of parameter**-

> Different functions can  have the same  graph. For example, suppose
>   that X  is a continuous vector-valued function defined on an interval
>   *I*  and suppose that u  is a real-valued function that is
>   differentiable with u’ never  zero on an interval *J*,  and such  that
>   the range of u is *I*. Then the function Y is defined on *J* by the
>   equation
>                      Y(t)=X[u(t)] is a continuous vector valued function having the same graph as X.

Why is u'never 0 an important condition?